# Logo não aparece no flutter dentro do container Gradient

Tags: android, flutter

Estou tentando colocar minha logo na pagina de login do meu app, mas não estou conseguindo.

*Obs.: Sou iniciante na linguagem e estou me adaptando ainda aos widgets.*

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [
              Color(0xFF01ECFD),
              Color(0xFF009AFA),
          ])),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 155.0,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/logo.png",
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 45.0),
            emailField,
            SizedBox(height: 25.0),
            passwordField,
            SizedBox(
              height: 35.0,
            ),
            loginButton,
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Tem alguma imagem de como deveria ficar? Ou alguma do que esse código gera pra você? Seja mais especifico na sua pergunta se você deseja obter alguma resposta, [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce configurou esse caminho de Assets no sey Yaml? Fiz um teste aqui com seu código e funcionou.. Usei uma imagem qualquer aqui do meu pc.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda foto, fonte, pacote, que você precisa adicionar no seu projeto, você precisa adicionar no seu arquivo, YAML. O próprio arquivo yaml vem comentado diversas coisas prontas de examplo para você seguir... dá uma olhada nele :)
Ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicionando o caminho do asset no seu yaml, provavelmente deve funcionar.

Luz no nosso caminho!

Comment: Vale mencionar que é necessário rodar ```flutter pub get``` direto do terminal ou usar o botão correspondente na IDE (caso ela possua).